# How do i assess a local variable outside function?

Tags: netcdf, local-variables

In this part of code i define a function to subset an area of interest. However, i want to use the variables latselect and lonselect later on in another function. So i have:

```
def DatasetToSubset(file, LatUpbound, LatLowBound, LonUpBound, LonLowBound):
    nc=netCDF4.Dataset(file)  
    lats=nc.variables['lat'][:]; lons=nc.variables['lon'][:]  
    latselect=np.logical_and(lats > LatLowBound, lats < LatUpBound)    
    lonselect=np.logical_and(lon > LonLowBound, lon < LonUpBound)  
    data=nc.variables['Runoff'][1000, latselect, lonselect]   
    return data; return latselect; return lonselect
```

Answer (score 1):

Once a function reaches a `return` statement, it returns that value and terminates immediately, meaning the subsequent two statements will never execute. You can return the three values as a tuple, like this

```
def DatasetToSubset(file, LatUpbound, LatLowBound, LonUpBound, LonLowBound):
    nc=netCDF4.Dataset(file)  
    lats=nc.variables['lat'][:]; lons=nc.variables['lon'][:]  
    latselect=np.logical_and(lats > LatLowBound, lats < LatUpBound)    
    lonselect=np.logical_and(lon > LonLowBound, lon < LonUpBound)  
    data=nc.variables['Runoff'][1000, latselect, lonselect]   
    return (data, latselect, lonselect)
```

and when you call this function, you can unpack the three values like this

```
(a, b, c) = DatasetToSubset(...)
```

`a` will hold the value of `data`, `b` that of `latselect`, and `c` that of `lonselect`.